# Foreach loop only outputting one value

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that should add a row to the table "notifications"

```
            $infoquery = "SELECT `user_id` FROM reply WHERE `post_id` = '" .$replyid. "'";
            $identifier = mysqli_query($dbc, $infoquery);
            $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($identifier);
            foreach(array_unique($rows) as $row){
            $core->addNotification($row['user_id'], $link, $description);
            }
```

however it is only adding one value, when it should add two notifications, one for user `1` and one for user `3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching only one single row, it should be like this:

```
 $infoquery = "SELECT `user_id` FROM reply WHERE `post_id` = '" .$replyid. "'";
 $identifier = mysqli_query($dbc, $infoquery);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($identifier)){
     $core->addNotification($row['user_id'], $link, $description);
 }
```

Comment: No, you iterate over the single first row, this means you'll get every column from this row, not every row.

Comment: @Core see my answer why you only go trough 1 item! (array_unique)

Comment: @Core: `mysql_fetch_array` fetches only a _single row_, not the _entire resultset_.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from tkausl's correct answer, your other problem is unique visitors: `array_unique` compares the *string* values of an the items in the array.

Let's look at this:

```
var_dump(strval(array("bob")), strval(array("ed")));
```

Which outputs:

```
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
```

(and a whole load of errors).

So, as their string representation is the same, if you expect an multidimensional array  `array(array("user"=>"bob"),array("user"=>"ed"))`, you will remain with only one entry in there. Now, there's a whole lot of ways to work around that in PHP, but your database is better at it, use:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM reply WHERE `post_id` = '" .$replyid. "'";
```

(But do look into prepared statements instead of adding raw parameters / query building).

Comment: I completely forgot about `SELECT DISTINCT`, thank you. I would mark @tkausl's answer correct but he didn't include what I needed in terms of unique.

Comment: His answer was your core problem though, I'd suggest you vote his answer as correct, and just leave mine hanging as an extra-long-comment-upgraded-to-answer. After his fix, you would no longer have only 1 entry added, you would as least have all the necessary entries, only doubled ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you have a small result set, you could use that result to get all the data at once and avoid using iteration to fetch the data by using $result->fetch_all according to the manual (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), as follows:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM reply WHERE `post_id` = '" .$replyid. "'";
$identifier = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query );

$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$rows = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
     $core->addNotification( $row['user_id'], $link, $description );
}
```